# AJAX to call remote files

Tags: php, ajax, cordova-plugins, html5-appcache, intel-xdk

this is my  poll code 
i'm getting data in Mysql

```
<form role="form" action="graduating_students_preview.php" method="post">
  <h3 class="style"> Student Performa</h3>



      <p>Department:</p>

        <select name="depart" required class="depart form-control btn-primary" >     
           <option value="">Department </option>
            <option value="computer science">Computer Science</option>
           <option value="zoology">Zoology</option>

  </select>

 <p>Degree</p>

  <select name="degree" class="degree form-control btn-primary" required > 
    <option value=""> Degree </option>
     <option value="computer science">Computer Science</option>
      <option value="chemistry">Chemistry</option>
       <option value="BBA">BBA</option>                          
  </select>


  <p>Semester</p>
 <select class="form-control btn-primary" name="semester" required>
  <option value="">semester</option>
       <option value="1st">FIRST (01)</option>
       <option value="2nd">SECOND (02)</option>
      <option value="3rd">THIRD (03)</option>
         <option value="4th">FOURTH (04)</option>
         <option value="05">FIFTH (05)</option>
        <option value="06">SIX (06)</option>
      <option value="07">SEVEN(07)</option>
       <option value="08">EIGHT (08)</option>
  </select></td>


       <p>Study Year</p>
  <select class="form-control btn-primary" name="study_year" required>
  <option value="" style="font-size:8px;">Select_year </option>
  <option value="2014" label="2014">2014</option>
  <option value="2013" label="2013">2013</option>
  <option value="2012" label="2012">2012</option>
  <option value="2011" label="2011">2011</option>
  <option value="2010" label="2010">2010</option>
  </select>


  <p>Faculty</p>

      <select name="faculty" class="faculty form-control btn-primary" required>
         <option value="">Faculty</option>
         <option value="science">Science</option>
         <option value="Arts geg">Arts</option>
         </select><br/>


         <div class="container">

      <p style="font-weight:bold">1. The work in the Program is too Heavy and induces a lot of 
     pressure</p>
        <div class="radio">
          <label><input type= "radio"  name = "q1" value="very satisfied">very satisfied</label>
        </div>
         <div class="radio">
          <label><input type= "radio"  name= "q1" value="satisfied">satisfied</label>
        </div>
         <div class="radio">
          <label><input type= "radio"  name="q1" value="uncertain">uncertain</label>
        </div>
```

and this is my PHP code

```
$db_name="performa";  // your database name  
$con=mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); //mysql connection  
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("can not select DB"); //select your database 
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); 
$depart = $_POST['depart'];  
$degree = $_POST['degree'];  
$semester = $_POST['semester']; 
$study_year = $_POST['study_year'];
$faculty = $_POST['faculty'];
$query = "INSERT INTO performa1 (depart,degree,semester,study_year,faculty) VALUES ('$depart', '$degree', '$semester', '$study_year', '$faculty')";  
mysql_query($query) or die('Query "' . $query . '" failed: ' . mysql_error());  
// name, email and address are fields of your fields; test your table. $name, $email and $address are values collected from the form  
?>
```

this is working fine in website but i want to use it in intel xdk and intel xdk dont support PHP/Mysql but we can do it with AJAX with JQUERY call PHP file 
i'm trying to do it but i dont know how to do it correctly 
so can anyone tell me where to place PHP file and how to do it with AJAX or different procedure 
i just want to get the data into database
Thanks

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/quessations/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: what should i add in this code ? newbee in PHP

Comment: It should replace the existing code you are using to access the database with.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run PHP or MySQL on most phones or tablets, so it doesn't make sense for a development kit targeting them to "support" them.

Write your server side code as a separate project. Then put the URL to an instance of that in your mobile app.

Comment: any idea using javascript to get information of this poll in txt file(XML) or other resources . i'm using intel xdk for HTML5 application .

Comment: You've recognised that you need to use Ajax. There are many Ajax tutorials that you can find with Google or other search engines. You might want to look for a Cordova specific one.

Answer (score 0):

I dont really undestand what you want to achieve: The title says '**AJAX to call remote files**'. If you want to send a request to the web server you need to set up this options on the jquery ajax:

```
xhrFields: {
     withCredentials: true
    },
crossDomain: true
```

You need cross domain access to request the web server because intel xdk apps internally they are a web server and that will give you cross domain error on the request.
Another thing you say '**i just want to get the data into database**' if you want to send the data to the database you just only need to send a request sending the form fields to the php file which have the procedure or query to be executed. If you have your html and php form together I recommend you to separate your server side code from your client side code. This will help you on maintenance in the future with bigger sites.